# Deleting a free app from iTunesConnect

Tags: app-store-connect

I have "developer removed from sale" an app from iTunesConnect. It was a free app. What happens to my users? Do they get to keep the latest version they downloaded in perpetuity or does it get removed when they next update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anybody have downloaded your app you can't delete the app on the device from the itunes connect. They have bought a product like in a supermarket. If you buy a thing it's yours.

Answer (score 0):

I you want it completely deleted from the appstore, you just tab the delete app button that now are under your app. that would remove the app completely from the appstore. if you just removed it from sale it would still just not appear, but it is still in apples database.

YES if they downloaded it before you removed it from sale they will still be able to use the app on their idevices.

Comment: A question ends with a single question mark, please save us the editing time :).